# Docker container start with comandline in java

Tags: java, docker, sparql, jena

I try to start a docker container with jena, but i get an `UnknownHostException`

My code:

```
        String sparqlHostDockerExecCmd = "docker run --name sparqlhost -p 3030:3030 -e ADMIN_PASSWORD=pw123 -e JVM_ARGS=-Xmx2g -d stain/jena-fuseki";
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sparqlHostDockerExecCmd);
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String sparqlDatasetURI = "http://sparqlhost:3030/UnitTestSet/update";
        testSink = new SparqlBasedSink(updateDatasetURI, queryDatasetURI);

        int retryCount = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {                      
                testSink.sendSomeUpdateRequestToJena();                    
                break;
            } catch (Exception error) {
                System.out.println("Could not connect, retrying");
                retryCount++;
                if (retryCount > 10) break;
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
        }
```

I got the `UnknownHostException` in the line

```
UpdateRequest request = UpdateFactory.create(sampleQuery);
UpdateProcessor proc = UpdateExecutionFactory.createRemote(request, updateDatasetURI);
proc.execute();
```

The `sampleQuery` is correct and i got the error in line 3.

The error message:

```
    org.apache.jena.atlas.web.HttpException: java.net.UnknownHostException: sparqlhost

    at org.apache.jena.riot.web.HttpOp.exec(HttpOp.java:1202)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.web.HttpOp.execHttpPost(HttpOp.java:803)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.web.HttpOp.execHttpPost(HttpOp.java:578)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.web.HttpOp.execHttpPost(HttpOp.java:534)
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.modify.UpdateProcessRemote.execute(UpdateProcessRemote.java:79)
    at org.aksw.simba.squirrel.sink.impl.sparql.SparqlBasedSink.sendAllTriplesToDB(SparqlBasedSink.java:83)
    at org.aksw.simba.squirrel.sink.impl.sparql.SparqlBasedSink.closeSinkForUri(SparqlBasedSink.java:70)
    at org.aksw.simba.squirrel.sink.impl.sparql.SparqlBasedSinkTest.openOpen(SparqlBasedSinkTest.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Comment: --name sparqlhost doesn't work as a host, Either declare a host entry or use your docker container ip, if it is local use localhost

Comment: i tried it with the container ip, but it doesn't work

Comment: Try adding these 2 lines to your dockerfile: `EXPOSE 3030
CMD ["httpd-foreground"]`

Answer (score 1):

From the piece of code I can figure out that you want to start container through your JAVA program and 
 you have assigned a name to the container (sparqlhost) and you want to use it as host name to access it further .
 however you local-host-machine doesn't know how to resolve : sparqlhost server name.

Since you have already bound 3030 to host machine , you can simple use your host-machine's name or IP address to process further.

Comment: i tried it with my ip address and it doesn't work. I get the same error

Comment: You do not have to use container's IP address , you have to use your host-machine's IP address where you are running this JAVA program.

Comment: i tied my host ip address also.